# Formatting the keys and values in a dictionary into a list of strings

Tags: python, dictionary, string.format

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{'name': 'Frank', 'job': 'coder', 'quality': 'just ok'}
```

I want to create a list using `.format` that creates a list like this:

```
["name(Frank)", "job(coder)", "quality(just ok)"]
```

I was hoping I could use a `{key}({value}).format(**dictionary)` kind of thing but I can't figure out how to do it. Do I have to loop with each entry to create the list?

Comment: `[f'{key}({value})' for key, value in dictionary.items()]`

Answer (score 0):

Use list-comprehension and an f-string for the task:

```py
dct = {'name':'Frank', 'job' : 'coder', 'quality' : 'just ok'}

lst = [f'{k}({value})' for k, v in dct.items()]
print(lst)
```

Prints:

```
['name(Frank)', 'job(coder)', 'quality(just ok)']
```